# fetch_array não retorna dados

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Estou fazendo uma listagem de usuários e os dados não aparecem na página. Esperei que aparecesse o nome do usuário, o tipo dele e a quantidade de posts e respostas que ele enviou ao sistema.
Há outro problema. Está cadastrado três usuários, mas aparece apenas um.
Abaixo está o código:

```
    <?php

        $conecta =  new MySQLi("localhost","root","","forum-ti-1");

    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-         scale=1">
    <title></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
            <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
                include('templates/header.html.php');
    ?>
                <div class="head_topics" style="top: 330px; left: 210px;">
                    <h2>Usuários</h2>
                </div>

                    <table class="t_subtopics" style=" top: 370px; left:210px;">
                            <?php
                                $usuario = "SELECT usuario.nome, situacao_usuario.descricao, COUNT(discussao.titulo) As posts, COUNT(resposta.conteudo) AS respostas 
                                FROM usuario, situacao_usuario, discussao, resposta 
                                WHERE usuario.id_situacao = situacao_usuario.id AND usuario.id = discussao.id_usuario AND usuario.id = resposta.id_usuario";
                                $lista = $conecta->query($usuario);
                                while($rs = $lista->fetch_array()){

                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 200px;">
                                    <div class="discussion_photo">
                                        <img src="images/profile-photo.jpg" style="height: 80px; width: 100px; display: block;"/>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 500px;">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><h3 style="font-size: 20px;"><? echo $rs['usuario.nome']; ?></h3></li>
                                        <li id="discussion_type_user" style="width: 80px; padding: 5px;"><? echo $rs['situacao_usuario.descricao']; ?></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 200px;">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><? echo $rs['posts']; ?> tópicos</li>
                                        <li><? echo $rs['respostas']; ?> respostas</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php

                                }

                            ?>

                    </table>
            <?php
                include('templates/footer.html.php');
    ?>
</body>
```

A figura abaixo mostra o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usei a consulta:

```
     "SELECT usuario.nome, situacao_usuario.descricao, COUNT(discussao.titulo) As posts, COUNT(resposta.conteudo) AS respostas 
                                                        FROM usuario, situacao_usuario, discussao, resposta 
                                                        WHERE usuario.id_situacao = situacao_usuario.id 
                                                        AND usuario.id = discussao.id_usuario 
                                                        AND usuario.id = resposta.id_usuario
                                                        GROUP BY usuario.id"
```

mas não retornou nenhum dado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Edição

A consulta no servidor funcionou, mas não apareceu na página:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(Edição)

Comment: `mysqli_error()` retorna algo?

Comment: Não, não retorna.

Comment: se você executar o sql diretamente no banco de dados, retorna alguma coisa?

Comment: "se você executar o sql diretamente no banco de dados, retorna alguma coisa? –  Euler01 "

Não, vou corrigir isso.

Comment: Continua aparecendo nada.

Comment: Tente assim `$conecta->query($usuario); var_dump($conecta->error());`, note que o `error` tem que ser usado após o query e não antes.

Comment: direto no banco de dados funciona o sql?

Comment: "direto no banco de dados funciona o sql? –  Euler01 3 mins atrás"

Não.

Comment: " 
Tente assim $conecta->query($usuario); var_dump($conecta->error());, note que o error tem que ser usado após o query e não antes. –  Guilherme Nascimento 5 minutos atrás "

Não retornou nenhum erro.

Comment: Se não esta retornando registro executando direto no banco de dados, o problema é no SQL. Verifique se há registro em todas as tabelas utilizadas no sql.
Se o id_situacao dos usuarios existe na tabela de situacao_usuario, se o usuario tem registro na discussao e na resposta.

Comment: Alterei o SQL da minha resposta, tenta rodar ele no banco de dados e me fala se retornou alguma coisa.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object

O problema está no fetch_array()...

Comment: A consulta está errada nesta parte "LEFT JOIN resposta ON usuario.id = resposta.id_usuario 
                                    GROUP BY usuario"'

Comment: Sim, claro. tinha uma virgula apos o trecho "ON usuario.id = discussao.id_usuario" retira ela.

Comment: Luana, se a minha resposta lhe resolveu o problema, marque-a como *correta*, caso contrario, informe que não funcionou. Notei que você tem várias perguntas com respostas, mas você não aceitou nenhuma, por favor aceite as respostas que lhe resolveram os seus problemas, a comunidade agrade-se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que encontrei o problema, você está usando `<?`, mas deveria estar usando `<?php`

Isto ocorre por que você está tentando usar [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag), porém as configurações do seu php.ini devem estar bloqueando o seu uso.

> **Nota:** Desde o PHP 5.4.0 a tag `<?=` está sempre disponível, independente das configurações no php.ini.
>
> **Nota:** `<?=` e `<? echo` tem o mesmo resultado, mas são diferentes, ou seja se o `short_open_tag` estiver desligado `<? echo` não irá funcionar, mas `<?=` irá funcionar.

Você pode usar:

```
<li><?php echo $rs['posts']; ?> tópicos</li>
```

ou

```
<li><?=$rs['posts']?> tópicos</li>
```

Segue o código corrigido:

```
<?php
    $conecta =  new MySQLi("localhost","root","","forum-ti-1");
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-         scale=1">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
            include('templates/header.html.php');
?>
                <div class="head_topics" style="top: 330px; left: 210px;">
                    <h2>Usuários</h2>
                </div>

                    <table class="t_subtopics" style=" top: 370px; left:210px;">
                            <?php
                                $usuario = "SELECT usuario.nome, situacao_usuario.descricao, COUNT(discussao.titulo) As posts, COUNT(resposta.conteudo) AS respostas 
                                FROM usuario, situacao_usuario, discussao, resposta 
                                WHERE usuario.id_situacao = situacao_usuario.id AND usuario.id = discussao.id_usuario AND usuario.id = resposta.id_usuario";
                                $lista = $conecta->query($usuario);
                                while($rs = $lista->fetch_array()){

                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 200px;">
                                    <div class="discussion_photo">
                                        <img src="images/profile-photo.jpg" style="height: 80px; width: 100px; display: block;"/>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 500px;">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><h3 style="font-size: 20px;"><?php echo $rs['usuario.nome']; ?></h3></li>
                                        <li id="discussion_type_user" style="width: 80px; padding: 5px;"><?php echo $rs['situacao_usuario.descricao']; ?></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 200px;">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><?php echo $rs['posts']; ?> tópicos</li>
                                        <li><?php echo $rs['respostas']; ?> respostas</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php

                                }

                            ?>

                    </table>
            <?php
                include('templates/footer.html.php');
    ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Como você está utilizando a função COUNT, ela agrupa os resultados. Por isso você precisa adicionar no final do SELECT um GROUP BY pelo id do usuário. Tenta assim:

```
SELECT 
  usuario.nome,
  situacao_usuario.descricao,
  COUNT(discussao.titulo) AS posts,
  COUNT(resposta.conteudo) AS respostas 
FROM  usuario 
  LEFT JOIN situacao_usuario    ON usuario.id_situacao = situacao_usuario.id 
  LEFT JOIN discussao       ON usuario.id = discussao.id_usuario
  LEFT JOIN resposta        ON usuario.id = resposta.id_usuario 
GROUP BY usuario.id
```